# Rails - redirect to don't save history

Tags: authentication, browser, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Devise for my app, and I customize the session controller to handle sign-in by otp code, my controller:

```rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
  end

  def create
    mobile_number = User.set_number(params[:mobile_number], params[:country_code])
    @user = User.active.fetch_user(nil, mobile_number)
    if @user
      otp = Sms.send_sms(mobile_number)
      if otp == false
        flash[:alert] = 'OTP Sending failed'
      else
        @user.otp = otp
        @user.otp_generated_at = Time.zone.now
        redirect_to sessions_otp_form_path(id: @user.id) if @user.save
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'User not found'
    end
  end
end
```

The routes:

```rb
  devise_for :users,
    path: '',
    path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', registration: 'signup', sign_up: '' },
    controllers: { sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations', passwords: 'passwords'}

  devise_scope :user do
    post '/send_otp', to:'sessions#send_otp'
    get 'sessions/otp_form'
```

My view:

```rb
<div class="login_form">
  <%= form_with model:@user, url:user_session_path do |f| %>
  ...
</div>
```

From the home page, I click to login button to go to `/login` page, if I input the correct number, I will be redirected to otp form(`sessions/otp_form`) where I can use the otp code to sign in. And the issue occurs here, when I am in otp form, I want to back to the previous page(the login page where I type my phone number) by clicking back on the browser, but the browser instead of steps back to the previous URL(/login in this case) it steps back two steps to go to home page.

I checked on browsers(both firefox and chrome), the `login` path didn't be stored.

To ensure the issue not coming from `redirect_to`, I create a simple form then submit -> redirect -> back in this case I can back to the previous URL step by step. I also created a simple app that using Devise without any customization, and it works well(doesn't lose the previous path). Currently, I'm not sure what is happening to my code. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It is not related to the back end. It due to my form:

```rb
<div class="login_form">
  <%= form_with model:@user, url:user_session_path do |f| %>
  ...
</div>
```

By default `form_with` attaches the `data-remote` attribute to the form. As a consequence, the form will be submitted using Ajax. That's why this history lost. So, to fix my issue, I disabled the default feature by adding: `local: true` option to the form. And it works.

```rb
<div class="login_form">
  <%= form_with model:@user, url:user_session_path, local: true do |f| %>
  ...
</div>
```